# Why do the lifetime rules discriminate in favor of string literals?

Tags: rust

This snippet doesn't compile because the struct `A` instance outlives the reference `s2` it holds in its field `s`. No problem.

```
struct A<'a> {
    s: &'a usize,
}

let s1 = 100;

let mut a = A { s: &s1 };

{
    let s2 = 1000;

    a.s = &s2;
}
```

In the same situation for string literals, it compiles. Why?

```
struct A<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
}

let s1 = "abc";

let mut a = A { s: &s1 };

{
    let s2 = "abcd";

    a.s = &s2;
}
```

Comment: because string literal have a static lifetime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per *The Rust Programming Language*, [all string literals have the special `'static` lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#the-static-lifetime).

So in your example you have an `A<'static>` and you're changing which `&'static str` it holds.

Comment: Actually, as I linked in a comment, all literals have the `'static` lifetime.

Comment: @Boiethios that's not fully true... in fact OPs post *shows* it isn't true as they are using the literal `100` / `1000`. It's only when you immediately take a reference to a literal can the compiler promote it to a `static` variable.

Comment: @Shepmaster Well, it depends what you call a literal. I'm not sure that 100/1000 is a literal.

Comment: @Boiethios `100` / `1000` is 100% a literal. A literal that is stored in a variable. If you take a reference to the literal, [it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=95c25c21aac510462c3063767a5428cb&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). In OP's case they are taking a reference to the variable and it doesn't.